# How to set the id of a 'label' HTML element?

Tags: html, css, label

If I have the following:

```
             <label for="deletetxt">Delete This Text</label>
```

What is the 'for' attribute here? Is that the id?

Assuming that I cannot set a class for the label element to style the label element, how do i set css for this element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two question, two answers:

1. What is the 'for' attribute here?

   It's here to tell the ID of the `<input>` element that label refers to. Some browsers will use it to set focus on that `<input>` element when user clicks on that `<LABEL>`
2. how do i set css for this element?

   A. If you want to CSS all label elements :

> ```
>       label {
>          /* your styles */
>       }
> ```

B. If you want to label that element, just use IDs or classnames as you usually do.

Answer (score 12):

The `for` attribute contains the ID of the element that the label is for. I always thought this would be quite intuitive...

```
<label for="SomeTextField" id="SomeLabel">Some text field</label>
<input type="text" id="SomeTextField">
```

You style a label like any other element:

```
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

I always thought this would be quite intuitive, as well. So - what are you *really* trying to do, the questions you ask are a sign that you have a different problem, actually.

Comment: Hi,
Well, the problem is - i'm setting label{ min-height: 30px;
} and the height is not changed.
The element has no other label styles applied to it.

Comment: @Mallika: `min-height` is not honored by all browsers, not in all rendering modes (i.e. quirks mode/standards mode - google "The Doctype Switch" to find out more) and AFAIK not for all element types (inline/block level elements). Recommended reading: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#min-max.

Answer (score 3):

The **for** attribute is the input/textarea/select that the label refers to.

You can still assign an **id** to the label:

```
<label id="myLabel" for="deletetxt">Delete This Text</label>
```

You can also wrap the input/textarea/select with the label in order to associate them without the **for** attribute.

```
<label id="myLabel">Delete This Text <input ... /></label>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `For` tells the label which element to belong to (which really means that when the label is clicked the element will get the focus).

As for your second question - you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):
- If your html is static use `$("label:eq(index)")`
- If your html is dynamic and you know the id of the element the label belongs to, you can use `$("label[for='thatid']")`

Comment: Ha. nuts you got there first!

Answer (score 1):

[HTML Label Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) is used for forms and submittion. it is not the ID, this 'for' should have the same name as the ID of the object connected to it - for example

```
<form>
<label for='ford'>Ford Car</label>
<input type="radio" name="fordCar" id="ford" />
</form>
```

Its a usability object really.

Answer (score 1):

"for" is the id of the form element that the label should be associated with.

You can add an id to the label to reference it directly.

```
<label for="fname" id="lbl-fname">First:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set an id as well as a class http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

the for "Specifies which form element a label is bound to" so when a user clicks on the label it focuses on the target input.

Answer (score 1):

With razor in Html I don´t find the best way for assign the id of a label, but you can assign the id in this way:

```
@Html.Label("© Integrantes Grupo:",new { @id="TitleIntegrants"} )
```