# How to display only certain text within a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

I'm using blogger to create posts and the post layout is as follows:

> Post Title
>
> Labels
>
> Content
>
> Author

When creating a post with multiple labels they will show like this for example:

> Labels: Alternative, New Music, Imagine Dragons

My question is, how could I go about displaying only the "Genre" in this case "Alternative" so it would display like this:

> Labels: Alternative

Blogger doesn't support php so this would have to be done i believe with JavaScript/jQuery where I could filter the text inside the labels div. However I'm not very skilled with that.

***UPDATE***
MANY THANKS TO Chirag64 FOR THIS!
Anyone using blogger will find this very useful in selecting certain labels to display on your posts.

Final product can be viewed here:

jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/13/

Comment: please provide some code... like your try

Comment: I have no idea how to code javascript and very little jquery :/

Comment: are you using css for styles???

Comment: Yeah I am I just have some basic css styling for the labels (font size/family, text color and link color) do you think this could be done using CSS?

Comment: You need to provide us with an example page or part of the HTML code so that we can help you use JavaScript on it.

Comment: As everyone says: post code to show what youve done and to show some effort...

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/kWJLb/1/

Comment: okay give me one sec I'll put some code inside jsfiddle

Comment: Okay here's a sample code from a post (this is the html that is displayed client side) http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following JavaScript code to remove the other genres except for the first one.

```
//Remove genres not matching the listOfGenres list
var labels = document.querySelectorAll(".post-labels a");
var listOfGenres = ["Alternative","Pop"];

for (i=0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (listOfGenres.indexOf(labels[i].textContent) == -1)
        labels[i].remove();
}

//Remove trailing commas.
var postLabels = document.querySelector(".post-labels");
postLabels.innerHTML = postLabels.innerHTML.replace(/\,/g, "");
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/6/).

Comment: Thanks for this code, The only problem with this method is that sometimes the first label to appear is not the label I intend to display. For example it would appear like "Labels: Imagine Dragons, Alternative" when I'm trying to display only the genre.

Comment: Changed my code to check for a list of genres which are saved as an array in the variable `listOfGenres`.

Comment: WOW that's exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you so much, one last issue, when I'm trying to save this script on blogger I'm getting this error "Error parsing XML, line 59, column 14: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup."

Comment: It's saying the markup somewhere here is not correct for (i=0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    if (listOfGenres.indexOf(labels[i].textContent) == -1)
        labels[i].remove();
}

Comment: Mark the code between the script tag as CDATA. Check this link for more info: http://yabtb.blogspot.in/2011/10/blogger-javascript-and-cdata.html

Comment: Wow thank you I got it to work!! One more thing haha the code you wrote for removing the trailing commas only works on the first instance of .post-header. So all the rest of the posts the commas still remain. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me I've updated the jsfiddle and am getting the same problems you can take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/8/

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.querySelector` to capture all post-labels elements instead of just the first one. Then remove commas from each of them one at a time using a for loop. http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/9/

Comment: Thank you so much, everything is working perfectly now!!! I can't thank you enough you deserve some props for all that :D here is the final product http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/11/ thanks again!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using css and jquery.

1) First separate each labels with seperate div's

2)Create a style for a class in css like

```
    .hidden-class
    {
        display:none;
    }
```

In jquery,on some condition add the hidden-class to the div.

```
      $( "id" ).addClass( "hidden-class" );
```

if you want to remove

```
      $( "id" ).removeClass( "hidden-class" );
```

in javascript
To add

```
        document.getElementById('id').className += 'hidden-class'
```

To remove

```
       document.getElementById("id").className = document.getElementById("id").className.replace(/\bhidden-class\b/,'');
```

Comment: Thanks this is a step in the direction I'm looking for. How could i select a certain label such as "Alternative" or "Pop" to add and id to it using this method?

Comment: Blogger labels are processed through their servers so they would all be wrapped in a div with the same label which is why I'm thinking I need to use some sort of javascript to select a certain text to add an ID to. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks! but I'm still having trouble selecting a text to add an id to

Comment: I've also updated my code as well and it does not seem to be working http://jsfiddle.net/3apZ4/5/ any ideas?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725585/how-to-set-the-id-of-a-label-html-element